# No rule to make target 'install'

Tags: software-installation, make, configure

I downloaded a package which in readme file suggested installing it with `./configure && make && make install`. After command exeuction, something worked and it was probably just `./configure && make`. I could not find the application installation, so I just entered

```
§ make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Does it mean that the application was not installed?

Comment: You need to run the commands from the directory where the source is located.

Comment: It means that the makefile in your package doesn't have a target "install" (or doesn't exist). You need to contact whoever made the package for assistance, or give *many, many* more details.

Comment: @Esther The Makefile should have the target, but OP probably runs from a wrong place.

Comment: @Pilot6 true, very possible

Comment: Looks like you downloaded *source code* (not a "package"). Compiling source code, and then installing the finished binary(ies) can be confusing and error-prone, especially when you are learning how. Keep in mind that it's not *packaged* software: When the time comes to maintain or uninstall it, apt and snap will be blind to it; you must keep track yourself and maintain maintain it yourself.

Comment: What software are you trying to install?

Comment: Apparently the configure script failed and exited with error(s).